# 1998 Volvo S70 beeping randomly

Tags: noise, volvo

I have a 1998 Volvo S70.

The question [here](http://www.volvo-forums.com/t5915-beeping.htm) sort of describes my problem, but I will be more specific.
At (apparently) random intervals, I will hear a short (half a second) beep coming from somewhere on the passenger side of the car. Sometimes they are consecutive- I have heard probably six or eight in a row- and sometime there is just a single beep. It is high-pitched, maybe around a G.

I asked my mechanic about it, and he suggested maybe there was a toy or something in the car. I have thoroughly cleaned the car, and found nothing. Beyond that, he had never heard of anything like what I described.

Like I stated, these beeps have no discernible pattern. At first I thought they occurred when I went over a bump, but then they happened when I was just driving, and even when I was waiting at a stop light. I have not heard them while I am in park.

They have been occurring with more and more frequency. In my twenty-five minute drive to work, my car beeps several hundred times. Apparently nothing is wrong with my car or my computer system, I keep it checked and in good condition.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know what causes it?

Comment: High pitched around a G, like a G musical note? Or G Gigahertz, which is probably outside the range of human hearing. See if you can shoot a video of the sound and upload it to youtube. I don't know if the [ECM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iWbNCf6SoQ) makes any noise but it's on the passenger side in the engine compartment.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of anything directly car related.  Got anybody that might be pranking you with one of these?  http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/8c52/

Comment: I highly doubt it, although I will look. That device is hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the climate control system can sometimes sound like a beep as the vents are adjusted.  You could check this by turning climate control completely off and repeating your drive.  No beep = climate control doing its thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, or certainly something very similar.

I had placed a bag with a couple of books in it on the passenger seat. Going over a bump was enough to make the bag press into the seat triggering the "someone's sitting on me" switch, and the beep was the seatbelt warning for the passenger side...

Seems silly to make such a detector switch so very sensitive.

Comment: That's a good guess, but isn't the seatbelt warning usually accompanied by a light on the dashboard? I'd think the OP would have noticed that.